# (permutation/Anagrm) words find in python 2.72 (need help to find what's wrong with my code)

Tags: python, cpu-word, permutation, anagram

i hope this request is legit.
i'm taking a programming course in python for engineers, so i'm kinda new at this business.
anyway, in my homework i was requested to write a function with receive two strings and check if one is a (permutation/Anagrm) of the other. (which means if they both have exactly the same letters and same number of appearances for each letter)

iv'e found some great codes here while searching, but i still don't get what's wrong with my code (and it's important for me to know for my studying process).

we got a tests file which suppose to check our functions, and it gave me that error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Or\Desktop\תכנות\4\hw4\123456789_a4.py", line 110, in <module>
test_hw4()
File "C:\Users\Or\Desktop\תכנות\4\hw4\123456789_a4.py", line 97, in test_hw4
test(is_anagram('Tom Marvolo Riddle','I Am Lord Voldemort'), True)
File "C:\Users\Or\Desktop\תכנות\4\hw4\123456789_a4.py", line 31, in is_anagram
s2_list.sort()
NameError: global name 's2_list' is not defined
```

this is my code:

```
def is_anagram(string1, string2):    

    string1 = string1.lower() #turns Capital letter to small ones
    string2 = string2.lower()
    string1 = string1.replace(" ","") #turns the words inside the string to one word
    string2 = string2.replace(" ","")

    if len(string1)!= len(string2):
        return False

    s1_list = [string1[i] for i in range(len(string1))] #creates a list of string 1 letters
    a2_list = [string1[k] for k in range(len(string1))]
    s1_list.sort()  #sorting the list
    s2_list.sort()
    booli=False
    k=0

    for i in s1_list: #for loop which compares each letter in the two lists
        if s1_list[k]==s2_list[k]:
            booli = True
            k=k+1
        else:
            booli=False
            break

    return booli
```

any one know how to fix it ?

Thanks!

Comment: @Vatine, editing the question in order to provide the answer (in a code comment) is poor form. It makes it falsely appear as though the questioner missed something that was already explicitly explained to him, which is unfair.

Comment: The entire function body can be replaced with `return sorted(string1.lower().replace(' ', '')) == sorted(string2.lower().replace(' ', ''))`. There is no need to make things even remotely as complicated as you are. Strings cannot be sorted in-place because they are immutable, but the `sorted()` function will accept an immutable sequence because it creates a new value. Also, Python already knows how to compare sequences element-wise.

Comment: Also, there is no need for such convolutions to turn a  list into a string. Just do `s1_list = list(string1)`

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you have a typo with `a2_list`.  That section should read:

```
s1_list = [string1[i] for i in range(len(string1))] #creates a list of string 1 letters
s2_list = [string2[k] for k in range(len(string2))]
s1_list.sort()  #sorting the list
s2_list.sort()
```

FWIW, here is an interactive prompt example of how to tell if two strings are anagrams of one another:

```
>>> string1 = 'Logarithm'
>>> string2 = 'algorithm'
>>> sorted(string1.lower()) == sorted(string2.lower()) # see if they are anagrams
True
```

Comment: On the second line of the third "paragraph", as it were. Should probably also refer to string2 rather than string1.

Comment: god, i really should precede my next optometrist visit....
thanks, youv'e been great help.

Comment: You might want to add the `.replace(' ', '')` step to the short solution... although really, we should strip out all punctuation going by the usual rules.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a `listify_string` function and use that to set your `s1_list` and `s2_list`, it might be easier to see that there are multiple things that look to be wrong with your code, unless you intended both s1_list and s2_list to be populated from the same string.

```
def listify(string):
    return [c for c in string]
```

Then you can simply do `s1_list = listify(string1)` and `s2_list = ...` to set the values.

I would probably turn at least the 'check if the two lists are the same' into a function, so I could use an early return to indicate falseness (so instead of starting with `booli` as true, setting it on each iteration through the loop and breaking out of the loop if false).

If you look at the `join` method of Python strings, you might find inspiration for another way to check if s1_list and s2_list are the same.

Comment: Or just use the `list` builtin: `list(string1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one-liner instead:

```
sorted(s1.lower().replace(' ', '')) == sorted(s2.lower().replace(' ', ''))
```

Python strings are essentially lists, so they can be sorted. We just need to take care of uppercase and whitespace first. The python equals operator then takes care of the actual comparison.